# Django connecting views.py and urls.py in Hello World in Django 3.0.6

Tags: django

I have created a djanogo project.

```
   manage.py
   db.sqlite3
   project/

      __init__.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      asgi.py
      wsgi.py 
      views.py
```

Then I have created the views.py as below.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Now how do I write the code for urls.py? I donot want to create a seperate folder as polls in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/. The following code works but how do i use the include() function in the urlpatterns?

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

Comment: you do not need to use `include()` because you are not using a separate app for the views, although that is the standard practice.

Comment: what is the name in the code:                                              
path('', views.index, name='index')

Comment: It is explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns